# Tell autoconf to use different version of gcc

Tags: openbsd, gcc, autoconf

OpenBSD installs newer version of gcc as egcc. I am trying to compile some software that requires gcc 4.4+ and can't seem to convince autoconf to use the newer versions of gcc...

I have tried:

```
# export CC=egcc
# $CC --version
#   egcc (GCC) 4.7.2
#   ...
```

and

```
# export CC=/usr/local/bin/egcc
# $CC --version
#   egcc (GCC) 4.7.2
#   ...
```

I even tried making symlinks to ~/bin and adding that to my PATH:

```
# cc --version
#   egcc (GCC) 4.7.2
#   ...

# gcc --version
#   egcc (GCC) 4.7.2
#   ...
```

and also:

```
# ./configure CC=egcc
# ./configure CC=/usr/local/bin/egcc
# CC=egcc ./configure
# CC=/usr/local/bin/egcc ./configure
```

But no matter what I still get:

```
configure: error: Only GCC 4.4 or newer supported
```

Will someone please show me the error of my ways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gah, it wanted g++...

```
# export CXX=eg++
```

Setting the environment variable `CXX` did the trick.